# Problema dando los valores deseados a una variable dentro de un for

Tags: php

Lo que necesito es que todo el `$array` se divida en piezas, formadas por 4 números cada una, exceptuando los dos primeros que indican el ancho y alto del puzle.

El problema es que aunque consigo darle los valores que quiero a la *pieza1*, luego el valor `$i=2`, por lo que la pieza siguiente será la pieza2 pero empezará a asignarle valores a la pieza desde el `array[2]` cuando lo que quiero es que a esa pieza se le asignen los siguientes 4 valores después de la *pieza1*, que serian `array[6]`, `array[7]`, `array[8]` y `array[9]`. El `length/alto` es para darle el número de piezas totales (16 en este caso).

NECESITO:

> pieza1:
> 2, 5, 4, 0
> pieza2:
> 2, 1 ,4, 2
> pieza3:
> 0, 1, 1, 0
> ...

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Muchas gracias a todos de antemano.

```
 <?php

    $array = [4, 4,
        2, 5, 4, 0,
        2, 1, 4, 2,
        0, 1, 1, 0,
        4, 4, 0, 3,
        0, 0, 4, 3,
        0, 0, 1, 1,
        1, 4, 0, 0,
        4, 4, 3, 5,
        5, 5, 2, 4,
        1, 1, 0, 5,
        4, 1, 0, 4,
        1, 0, 2, 4,
        3, 5, 1, 2,
        1, 4, 2, 0,
        0, 1, 5, 2,
        1, 5, 0, 4];

    function tamanioYpiezas($arrayPiezas){
        $length = count($arrayPiezas);

        $alto = $arrayPiezas[0];
        $ancho = $arrayPiezas[1];

        for($i = 0; $i < ($length/$alto); $i++){
            ${"pieza".$i} = [];
            for($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++){
                array_push(${"pieza".$i}, $arrayPiezas[$i+$j+1]);
            }
        }
        print_r($pieza1);
    }

    tamanioYpiezas($array);
    ?>
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @Comunidad solucionado? se entiende mejor ahora?

Comment: ¿A qué quieres llegar exactamente o qué quieres hacer con esto? Me parece que estás rompiendo el coco sin necesidad con todo esto. Conviene siempre explicar con claridad el contexto y la finalidad para que podamos ayudarte mejor, por ejemplo, ¿qué justifica en este caso el tener que crear variables dinámicas? Si es para una salida por pantalla esto no es necesario, sería sobrecargar el código.

Comment: Sería bueno que tu pregunta comenzara con "Estoy haciendo/programando un rompecabezas...". De principio ¿por qué no manejas el alto y ancho en variables diferentes? Si necesitaras otro valor ¿también lo meterías en `$array`?.

Comment: $array son las distintas piezas de un puzle, este esta formado por el alto y el ancho que son los dos primeros nimeros del array, el resto, cada 4 numeros, por eso esta dividio en lineas son las piezas del puzle, necesito sacar de ese array cada pieza individualmente para luego poder trabajar con ellas pero no consigo hacerlo, el problema que me surge para hacerlo creo que esta bien explixado en el enunciado inicial, si no se entiende algo mas preguntad por favor, michas gracias

Comment: no sé si te entendí bien el problema pero prueba iniciar el for en la posicion 2, en vez de la posicion 0.